# JS/ES6: How to get specific fields of object array and return a single object with specific value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an object array like this:

```
const schema = [
    { placeholder: 'Title', name: 'title' },
    { placeholder: 'Authors', name: 'author' },
    { placeholder: 'Publisher',  name: 'publisher', optional: true },
    { placeholder: 'Edition', name: 'edition', optional: true }
]
```

Now I would like to get an object with all `name` fields as key with `1` value:

```
result = { 'title': 1, 'author': 1, 'publisher': 1, 'edition': 1 }
```

I tried to use `map`, but

```
schema.map(o => { return o.name })
```

gives me just an array:

```
['title', 'author', 'publisher', 'edition']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `reduce`

```js
const schema = [
    { placeholder: 'Title', name: 'title' },
    { placeholder: 'Authors', name: 'author' },
    { placeholder: 'Publisher',  name: 'publisher', optional: true },
    { placeholder: 'Edition', name: 'edition', optional: true }
]

console.log(schema.reduce((acc, {name}) => (acc[name] = 1, acc), {}))
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const schema = [
    { placeholder: 'Title', name: 'title' },
    { placeholder: 'Authors', name: 'author' },
    { placeholder: 'Publisher',  name: 'publisher', optional: true },
    { placeholder: 'Edition', name: 'edition', optional: true }
];

console.log(schema.reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc[current.name] = 1;
  
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use  `Object.assign` and the spread syntax:

```
Object.assign(...schema.map(o => ({ [o.name]: 1 })));
```

```js
const schema = [
    { placeholder: 'Title', name: 'title' },
    { placeholder: 'Authors', name: 'author' },
    { placeholder: 'Publisher',  name: 'publisher', optional: true },
    { placeholder: 'Edition', name: 'edition', optional: true }
];

const result = Object.assign(...schema.map(o => ({ [o.name]: 1 })));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The most ES*Next*y answer :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, thanks for the appreciation, but strictly speaking this only uses ES2015 features ([`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [`=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [object literals with dynamic property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)).

Answer (score 1):

You can first create an object and the use `forEach` loop to add properties.

```js
const schema = [
  { placeholder: 'Title', name: 'title' },
  { placeholder: 'Authors', name: 'author' },
  { placeholder: 'Publisher',  name: 'publisher', optional: true },
  { placeholder: 'Edition', name: 'edition', optional: true }
]

var obj = {}
schema.forEach(o => obj[o.name] = 1)
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map` will always give you an array. Since you want to convert you array of objects to single object, it makes sense to use `.reduce` instead.

```
schema.reduce( (a, c) => {
  a[c.name] = 1;
  return a;
} , {});
```